# 2013 IMO Shortlist A1 Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-explanation, contest-math, fake-proofs

https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2013SL.pdf

I'm wondering if there's a mistake in the first of the solutions given to A1, or rather that the proof is just insufficient. I agree that the given expression can be proved by induction and then I thought something interesting was about to happen, but instead it just says,

"applying (1) to the sequence given by $b_k=a_{n-k}$, the expressions coincide"

That seems to me to be more or less restating what we're trying to prove. Yes the reflected products are of the same form with a minimal index gap of 2 but there's no justification for why they should coincide.

Am I missing something?

Comment: write out $n=2$ and $n=3$

Comment: I know it's true from experimenting, but I can't see how that "proof" proves it.

Comment: The solution is correct and complete as written. Perhaps, instead of being so focused on explicit values $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$, think about the first part as proving a statement for a sequence $ C_1, C_2, \ldots$, and then applying it to $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ and $(a_n, a_{n-1},\ldots, a_1)$.  $\quad$ If you're still stuck on the reasoning, consider how one can prove a similar and simplified problem where $u_i = u_{i-1} + a_i$ and $v_i = u_{i - 1 } + a _{n+1 - i } $, then show that $u_n = \sum a_i = v_n$.